# Conditional Probability Answer Verification

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Consider two urns U and V such that:

Urn U contains four white balls and two red balls.

Urn V contains two white balls and three red balls.

In this part, the player selects at random one ball from the urn U and puts it in the urn V. Then, he selects two balls simultaneously and randomly from the urn V.

Consider the following events:

W: The ball selected from the urn U is white.

D: The two balls selected from the urn V have different colors.

1) Verify that $P(D/W)=\frac{3}{5}$ and then calculate $P(D\cap W)$

2) Calculate $P(D)$

3) Knowing that the two balls selected from urn V have the same color, what is the probability that the ball selected from the urn U is white?

My answers are:

1) $P(D\cap W)=\frac{2}{5}$

2) $P(D)=\frac{26}{45}$

So far, I was pretty sure in my answers, but in the last part, I got $\frac{12}{19}$ while almost all my classmates (some got nonsensical answers) got $\frac{18}{19}$.

I asked someone and he said I was correct (not a classmate), but I am not so sure. Thanks in advance. Also, I think they got the same answers in previous parts, but not sure. So please verify those if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf P(D) = \mathsf P(D\cap W)+\mathsf P(W^\complement)\,\mathsf P(D\mid W^\complement) = \tfrac 25+\tfrac 1 3 (\tfrac 2 6 \tfrac4 5+ \tfrac 4 6 \tfrac 2 5) = \tfrac {26} {45}$

$\mathsf P(W\mid D^\complement) = \frac{\mathsf P(D^\complement\mid W)\;\mathsf P(W)}{\mathsf P(D^\complement)} = \tfrac{(1-3/5)(2/3)}{1-26/45} = \tfrac{12}{19} $

Comment: Sorry but we want D bar dont we? I mean, same colors.

Comment: @HasanSaad.  Ah, yes.  Thank you.  Now, adjusted.

Comment: Why is $P(W)=\frac{1}{3}$? Isn't it $\frac{4}{6}$? Sorry if that's stupid. Also, I didn't use this method because I never learned Bayes's rule, although I knew it from messing around. What I did was:

$P(W|D^C)=\frac{P(W\cap D^C)}{P(D^C)}=\frac{P(W)-P(W\cap D)}{1-P(D)}=\frac{12}{19}$.

Is that correct or wrong?

Comment: @HasanSaad Yes.  This is what I get for checking before the morning coffee.

Comment: Haha, it's night in here. :P 
Also, is my method correct?

Comment: Also, if you're sure of the answer, it means almost everyone in class (Actually I think it is everyone, but just in case I forgot someone) got it wrong and I got it right. I really wonder how one can get $\frac{18}{19}$

Comment: @HasanSaad, Yes. $\mathsf P(D^\complement\cap W)= \mathsf P(W)-\mathsf P(D\cap W)=\mathsf P(W)\big(1-\mathsf P(D\mid W)\big)$

Comment: Thanks, though we already had $P(D\cap W)$ from part 1.